# Java equals implementation for two objects of the same class returns false when checking getClass()

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

I have implemented `hashCode()` and `equals()` for an object using the default from NetBeans:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 5;
    hash = 37 * hash + this.unitSystemID;
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    LOGGER.debug(getClass().toString());
    LOGGER.debug(this.getClass().getClassLoader().toString());
    LOGGER.debug(obj.getClass().toString());
    LOGGER.debug(obj.getClass().getClassLoader().toString());
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final UnitSystem other = (UnitSystem) obj;
    if (this.unitSystemID != other.unitSystemID) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

At the logging check-points, I get:

> units.UnitSystem - class
>   com.utilities.domain.units.UnitSystem
>
> units.UnitSystem -
>   org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@42d353e2
>
> units.UnitSystem - class
>   com.utilities.domain.units.UnitSystem_$$_jvst6b1_19ed
>
> units.UnitSystem -
>   org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@42d353e2

The equality fails at that point and `equals` returns false.

What is the extra `_$$_jvst6b1_19ed`?  Where does it come from?

From what I understand, the classes should be equal if they are from the same class loader, which these are.  I have not had a problem with this implementation anywhere else I have used it.  Why is `getClass()` returning different things?

Comment: Can you share the code where you are trying to compare two objects? and can you share your UnitSystem class's source? what type is unitSystemID?

Comment: `UnitSystem_$$_jvst6b1_19ed` is likely a dynamically generated *proxy* subclass for code injection, e.g. as implemented by Hibernate for lazy loading.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi  I am comparing the objects like `if (opt.get().getDrawingRevision().getUnitSystem().equals(opt.get().getUnitSystem())) {...}`.  The unitSystemID is just an `int`.  I could post the code, but I don't think it really matters for the question.

Comment: @Andreas  Something from Hibernate would make sense, since I am using that.  What is the right way to compare classes in that scenario?  Should I use `getName()`?

Comment: @Tim: Can you debug your program and see what exactly returns false? Why not try using instance of operator for checking if object is of that class? I know its not very recommended way but see if that works?

Comment: @Tim Unless you actually subclass `UnitSystem` yourself, exact class matching isn't necessary, so replace `getClass() != obj.getClass()` with `! (obj instanceof UnitSystem)`. You can't make `UnitSystem` class `final` since you want Hibernate to be able to create a subclass proxy, so you don't have absolute guarantee that `UnitSystem` won't be subclassed by non-Hibernate code, but is such an absolute guarantee really needed?

Comment: @Andreas  If you want to create an answer, I will accept it.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you actually subclass `UnitSystem` yourself, exact class matching isn't necessary, so replace

```
if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
    return false;
}
```

with

```
if (! (obj instanceof UnitSystem)) {
    return false;
}
```

You can't make `UnitSystem` class `final` since you want Hibernate to be able to create a subclass proxy, so you don't have absolute guarantee that `UnitSystem` won't be subclassed by non-Hibernate code, but is such an absolute guarantee really needed?

Answer (score 0):

As @Andreas said in a comment it usually happens when the object has been fetched by a lazy loading. To get the initial object you should to unproxy it first. Here is an example of the unwrapper for a `Hibernate`

```
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public static <T> T initializeAndUnproxy(T entity) {
    if (entity == null) {
      throw new InternalServerException("Entity passed for initialization is null");
    }

    T unproxy = entity;
    Hibernate.initialize(entity);
    if (isProxy(entity)) {
      unproxy = (T) ((HibernateProxy) entity).getHibernateLazyInitializer().getImplementation();
    }
    return unproxy;
  }

  public static <T> boolean isProxy(T entity) {
    return entity instanceof HibernateProxy;
  }
```

Comment: So this is something I would add to my `UnitSystem` class, and then in the equals implementation use `initializeAndUnproxy(getClass()) != initializeAndUnproxy(obj.getClass())`?

Comment: Yes, as an option. But you shouldn't add this at you entity class. You should better create some helper class and do method call as `static`

Comment: Not sure if I was doing something wrong (apparently so), but I couldn't get this to work.  It ran, and went through the `initializeAndUnproxy` method, but it didn't change the equality, so it returned false at the same point.